# What is the best way to forward visitors to my homepage to an external site but leave the backlinks accessible?

Tags: 7, redirection

Maybe not distinctly a Drupal question, I have an older Drupal 7 site that I want to leave up for backlinks, but any new visitors I want to redirect to a new external website.  So `domain.com` would redirect to `newdomain.com` but `domain.com/node/6` is still accessible.

Update: Server is nginx and I don't have access to server settings and routes.

Comment: Sounds potentially like an htaccess rule. You could write one that matches the domain directly, and that should allow non-homepage URLs to keep working. Maybe something like this in your .htaccess file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493408/redirect-root-but-not-subfolders this should redirect any home request to the new domain, but anything not matching should continue to work. It _might_ need a little massaging for Drupal, but I don't have a way to test this out at the moment. Initial tests here tell me it will work. https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Sorry, updated the question it is an nginx server and I don't have access to the nginx routes/settings files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like one thing you could do is edit the themes `template.php` file and do something like:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $url = 'http://newdomain.com';
    drupal_goto($url, ['external' => TRUE], 301);
    // perhaps alternatively you could use header();
  }
}
```

Outside of doing this at the web server level, it might be the smallest change to do it.